# Get viewport coordinates from mapView? regionDidChanged swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

The following function is called when the user moved the map.

It is possible to get the viewport? Viewport is latitude and longitude of north/east and the lat. and lon. of south/west.

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool){
    print("The \(mapView.centerCoordinate)")
    print("the maprect \(mapView.visibleMapRect.origin)")
    print("the maprect \(mapView.visibleMapRect.size)")
    //I find just this attributes for mapView

    }
```

I don't know how get the viewports out of my data. I can't find anything in the www.

The destination is that I log the coordinates with google analytics and another tool evaluate the datas.

Has somebody an idea? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**MapKit**

```
let northEast = mapView.convertPoint(CGPoint(x: mapView.bounds.width, y: 0), toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
let southWest = mapView.convertPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: mapView.bounds.height), toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
```

**googleMaps**

mapView has a property "projection" where you can use "coordinateForPoint" to convert a point from the mapView to a coordinate. so the following could work:

**swift 3 for google maps**

```
let northEast = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: CGPoint(x: mapView.layer.frame.width, y: 0))
let southWest = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: CGPoint(x: 0, y: mapView.layer.frame.height))
```

**swift 2**

```
let northEast = mapView.projection.coordinateForPoint(CGPoint(x: mapWidth, y: 0 ))
let southWest = mapView.projection.coordinateForPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: mapHeight))
```

you just need to enter your mapView width and height

Answer (score 4):

Based on [fel1xw answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36476677/2213459)

### Swift 3 MapKit

```
let northEast = mapView.convert(CGPoint(x: mapView.bounds.width, y: 0), toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
let southWest = mapView.convert(CGPoint(x: 0, y: mapView.bounds.height), toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
```